# ClassCastException using JTable?

Tags: java, swing, exception, jtable, awt

```
renbor = tabla_proveedor.getSelectedRow();
DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) tabla_proveedor.getModel();
modelo.removeRow(renbor);
```

That line of code gives me an error, it gives me...

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JTable$1 cannot be cast to javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel

How do I fix that? I need to remove a row from my table.

This is where I instantiate tabla_proveedor

```
tabla_proveedor=new JTable(datos_proveedor,columna_proveedor)

    { 
        public boolean isCellEditable(int datos_proveedor, int columna_proveedor){

        return false;
        }
        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer r, int datos_proveedor, int columna_proveedor)
        {
            Component c= super.prepareRenderer(r,datos_proveedor,columna_proveedor);

            return c;
        }
        };
```

Comment: Print `tabla_proveedor.getModel().getClass().getName()` to know the class of the model.

Comment: javax.swing.JTable$1
what do I do with that? I'm a new programmer

Comment: What about using `TableModel model = tabla_proveedor.getModel();`? `AbstractTableModel` might work as well.

Comment: However, if you want to manipulate the data of the table dynamically, I'd write a custom model that extends `AbstractTableModel` and maintains an ArrayList of data.

Comment: How do you instantiate `tabla_proveedor`?

Comment: Edited the question for you to see

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> javax.swing.JTable$1 what do I do with that?

When you specify the data and column names as arrays the JTable creates an anonymous inner class for the TableModel. The "$1" tells you this is the case.

An easier way to create the JTable is you use the constructor that takes Vectors. If you have to use the arrays, then you need to create the DefaultTableModel manually (as suggested by Sanjay):

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames)
JTable table = new JTable( model );
```

> But I use getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(200);

This has nothing to do with the TableModel that is being used, so yes this code will still work with the DefaultTableModel.

Answer (score 3):

You should set the table model manually, when you create the table:

```
table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel());
```

This might typically go in the constructor or in the GUI-init method after you've added the table to the form.

This way you know what the class is.
You can customise it if you want.

Comment: But I use 

`getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(200);`

And with DefaultTableModel I can't is there a way to remove the row, and give PreferredWidth?